# Split string keeping the separator without a starting space

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-re

Hi I would like to split some strings like these using **python re module**:

```
str1 = "-t Hello World -a New Developr -d A description"
str2 = "-t Bye -a sometext -d a large description"
```

I must keep the `-` because I'm currently programming a python CLI project.
I've tried using

```
re.split(r'(?=-)',aux)
```

but I recieved

```
['', '-t Hello World  ', '-a Author ', '-d Description ']
```

instead of

```
['-t Hello World', '-a Author', '-d Description']
```

Any recommendation?

Comment: FWIW if you use an argument parsing library like argparse, you don't need to worry about stuff like this. BTW welcome to SO! Check out [ask] if you want advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a negative lookbehind to avoid splitting at the start of the string: `(?<!^)`

Then strip each of the resulting strings.

```
for s in str1, str2:
    print([x.strip() for x in re.split(r'(?<!^)(?=\s+-)', str1)])
```

(I also added `\s+` to avoid splitting words like `Spider-Man`.)

Output:

```
['-t Hello World', '-a New Developr', '-d A description']
['-t Hello World', '-a New Developr', '-d A description']
```

---

However, I'd recommend looking into libraries that can do this for you - maybe **argparse** and **shlex** to start, and I would question where these strings are coming from, cause normally you deal with command line arguments as a list before parsing, like this:

```
['-t', 'Hello', 'World', '-a', 'New', 'Developr', '-d', 'A', 'description']
```

Comment: Ty totally worked for me! I will take notes about argparse and shelx for future projects. In this one I must keep it as similar to C lang as possible so I'm using getotp.getotp. I appreciate your help and your quickly answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try applying the strip() method on the results.

```
foo = re.split(r'(?=-)',str1)
foo = [s.strip() for s in foo]
```